# Not able to connect to SQL Server using configuration manager

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database using the configuration manager.

The config file code:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS"
         connectionString="data source =.\\SQLEXPRESS; database = Sample2; integrated security = SSPI;"
         providerName ="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The C# code below:

```
string SC = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

//string SC = ("data source =.\\SQLEXPRESS; database = Sample2; Integrated Security = SSPI;");
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SC);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblemployee", con);
con.Open();

GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

When I try to run the application I get an error at

```
con.Open();
```

Error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Instance failure.

Please help.

Comment: And what might be the error that you get?

Comment: Sorry. An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Instance failure.

Answer (score 2):

You need only one `\` before `SQLExpress` in your connection string:

```
<add name="DBCS"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; database = Sample2;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
```

Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#sse) for further details

Comment: I agree to remove the extra slash.  Otherwise,  Instance failure exception occurs.

Comment: Thank you it works now. When I had put a single "\" directly into the cs it did not work. It only worked when had put double "\". What is the reson for that?

Comment: You can either use `Initial Catalogue` or `database` ... both the correct and valid.

Comment: @user3186277, connection string in config file don't need `//` only in .cs file it's needed for escaping.

Comment: You need the a double `\ ` in C# code to escape the `\ ` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx), however, you don't have to do this in the config file.

Comment: @Jaco The other option would be to use the @ symbol to declare the connection string as a string literal, thus not having to worry about escaping anything.  ex:   connectionString = @"Data srouce=.\SQLEXPRESS